# What should the appropriate series tag be called?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I was editing [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/11663/2604) in the review queue. What should the tag for the relevant series be? I have a feeling the official English title (or the romanised one) is too long for a tag name, so I put it down as `retag` for now. In general, what should be done about cases like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, not sure what to do with this one. `soredemo-sekai-wa-utsukushii` is 28 characters (too long); `the-world-is-still-beautiful` is also 28 characters (still too long).

We could use `world-is-still-beautiful` (24 characters, works), maybe. Or perhaps `the-world-still-beautiful` (25 characters, works). That's probably better than `soreseka`, which, while the official abbreviation for the name, is not really used outside Japan as far as I can tell.

UPDATE: I added both `world-is-still-beautiful` and `the-world-still-beautiful` as synonyms for `soreseka`. An ugly solution, but it's better than nothing.